# JS - efficient way to map a list of strings to an equal length matrix

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, matrix

I'm looking at a [problem solution on leetcode](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/63423/1-liner-python), and there is a clever solution that uses Python's map function to transpose a list of string to an equal size matrix like so:

```
t = map(None, *words)
```

**Explanation**:

The map(None, ...) transposes the "matrix", filling missing spots with None. For example:

```
["abc",           [('a', 'd', 'f'),
 "de",     =>      ('b', 'e', None),
 "f"]              ('c', None, None)]
```

I was wondering if I can achive similar goal with a **js** gist

Comment: Were you just wondering or have you tried anything? It's not nice to disguise programming assignments as questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To create a matrix ( with equal lengths ):*

```
solution=array.reduce((solution,el)=>(el.split("").forEach((letter,index)=>(solution[index]=solution[index]||[]).push(letter)),solution),[]);
//if you really need the *undefineds* :
maxlength=array.reduce((length,arr)=>Math.max(length,arr.length),0);
solution.forEach(el=>el.length=maxlength);
```

http://jsbin.com/nisoderini/edit?console
Explanation left away for a reason...

*To check for equal length arrays in an array:*

```
length=array.reduce((length,arr,i)=>!i?arr.length:(length?(arr.length==length?length:false):false),0);
```

Length is false if array is not a symmetric matrix...

*to check for a square matrix*

```
square=array.every(arr=>arr.length==array.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it.

```js
function transpose(mat, replacement){
    const len = findMaxArr(mat);
    const res = [];
    // loop through each row...
    mat.map(e => {
        const currElemArr = e.split('')
        if (e.length === len) {
            res.push(currElemArr);
        } else {
            // if current row len is less than max len
            // pad it with the replacement variable
            const diff = len - e.length;
            const currElemArrPadded = currElemArr.concat(createRepArr(replacement, diff));
            res.push(currElemArrPadded);
        }
    });
    return res;
}

// create an array of inp of length len
function createRepArr(inp, len) {
    const res = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        res.push(inp);
    }
    return res;
}

// find maximum length array of string in a string array
function findMaxArr(mat) {
    let res = 0;
    mat.forEach(m => {
        if (m.length > res) {
            res = m.length;
        }
    });
    return res;
}

const data = ["abc", "de", "f"];
console.log(transpose(data, 0));
```